# Chrome Extension API Calls order and DOM Information

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm working on an extension that is supposed to extract information from the DOM based specific classes/tags,etc, then allow the user to save the information as a CSV file.

I'm getting stuck on a couple of places and haven't been able to find answers to questions similar enough.

Where I am tripped up at is:
**1) Making sure that the page has completely loaded so the chrome.tabs.query doesn't return null a couple of times before the promise actually succeeds and allows the blocksF to successfully inject.** I have tried placing it within a settimeout function but the chrome api doesn't seem to work within such the function.

**2) Saving the extracted information so when the user moves onto a new page, the information is still there.** I'm not sure if I should use the chrome.storage api call or simply save the information as an array and keep passing it through. It's just text, so I don't believe that it should take up too much space.

Then main function of the background.js is below.

```
let mainfunc = chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
async(id, tab) => {

    if (buttonOn == true) {

        let actTab = await chrome.tabs.query({
            active: true,
            currentWindow: true,
            status: "complete"
        }).catch(console.log(console.error()));
        if (!actTab) {
            console.log("Could not get URL. Turn extension off and on again.");
        } else {
            console.log("Tab information recieved.")
        };

        console.log(actTab);

        let blocksF = chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: actTab[0]['id'] },
                func: createBlocks
            })
            .catch(console.error)
        if (!blocksF) {
            console.log("Something went wrong.")
        } else {
            console.log("Buttons have been created.")
        };

        /*
        Adds listeners and should return value of the works array if the user chose to get the information
        */
        let listenersF = chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: actTab[0]['id'] },
                func: loadListeners
            })
            .catch(console.error)
        if (!listenersF) {
            console.log("Listeners failed to load.")
        } else {
            console.log("Listeners loaded successfully.")
        };
        console.log(listenersF)
    };

});
```

Information from the DOM is extracted through an event listener on a div/button that is added. The event listener is added within the loadListeners function.

```
let workArr = document.getElementById("getInfo").addEventListener("click", () => {

    let domAr = Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll(<class 1>, <class 2>),
        el => {
            return el.textContent

        }
    );

    let newAr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < domAr.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            newAr.push([domAr[i], domAr[i + 1]])
        }
    }


    newAr.forEach((work, i) => {
        let table = document.getElementById('extTable');
        let row = document.createElement("tr");
        row.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).textContent = work[0];
        row.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).textContent = work[1];
        table.appendChild(row);
    });

    return newAr
```

I've been stuck on this for a couple of weeks now. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues.

1. `chrome` methods return a Promise in MV3 so you need to `await` it or chain on it via `then`.
2. `tabs.onUpdated` listener's parameters are different. The second one is a change info which you can check for `status` instead of polling the active tab, moreover the update may happen while the tab is inactive.
3. `catch(console.log(console.error()))` doesn't do anything useful because it immediately calls these two functions so it's equivalent to `catch(undefined)`
4. Using `return newArr` inside a DOM event listener doesn't do anything useful because the caller of this listener is the internal DOM event dispatcher which doesn't use the returned value. Instead, your injected `func` should return a Promise and call `resolve` inside the listener when done. This requires Chrome 98 which added support for resolving Promise returned by the injected function.

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onTabUpdated);

async function onTabUpdated(tabId, info, tab) {
  if (info.status === 'complete' &&
      /^https?:\/\/(www\.)?example\.com\//.test(tab.url) &&
      await exec(tabId, createBlocks)) {
    const [{result}] = await exec(tabId, loadListeners);
    console.log(result);
    // here you can save it in chrome.storage if necessary
  }
}

function exec(tabId, func) {
  // console.error returns `undefined` so we don't need try/catch,
  // because executeScript is always an array of objects on success
  return chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: {tabId}, func})
    .catch(console.error);
}

function loadListeners() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    document.getElementById('getInfo').addEventListener('click', () => {
      const result = [];
      // ...add items to result
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: The difficulty I'm still having is that even when status = complete, the createBlocks function isn't called. the onTabUpdated function just finishes

Comment: Since I don't see your actual code I can only guess your condition for the URL is incorrect, because it's the only thing between the check for status and exec.